# How can the self join on a table return more rows than actual data present in the table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

This query 1 is returning 9 rows which is returning one row with extra division code `AII`, while in the table `TRAIN_RUNNING_INFO`, there are records pertaining to only one division `JU` which can be verified from the Output of query 3. Please guide why is the 1st query returning records for an extra division AII .

--------------------Query 1-----------------------

```
 SELECT A.TRAIN_ID,A.TRAIN_NUMBER,A.TRAIN_START_DATE,A.SOURCE,A.DESTINATION,B.DIVISION_CODE,B.STATION_CODE,A.SCHEDULED_DATE,
    B.ACTUAL_DATE,B.ACTUAL_TIME,A.ACTUAL_DATE AS REPORT_DATE FROM
     (
      SELECT DISTINCT TRAIN_ID,TRAIN_NUMBER,TRAIN_START_DATE,ACTUAL_DATE,SOURCE,DESTINATION,SCHEDULED_DATE,MY_RANK FROM
      (
     SELECT DISTINCT TRAIN_ID,TRAIN_NUMBER,TRAIN_START_DATE,ACTUAL_DATE,SOURCE,DESTINATION,DIVISION_CODE,SCHEDULED_DATE
     ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TRAIN_ID,TRAIN_START_DATE ORDER BY ACTUAL_DATE DESC ,ACTUAL_TIME DESC)AS MY_RANK
     FROM TRAIN_RUNNING_INFO
                WHERE TRAIN_CATG='L'
                AND TRAIN_ID='BGK 140920212028'
        )WHERE MY_RANK=1 AND ACTUAL_DATE='15-Sep-2020'
     )A,TRAIN_RUNNING_INFO B
     WHERE A.TRAIN_ID=B.TRAIN_ID
     AND A.TRAIN_START_DATE=B.TRAIN_START_DATE
      ORDER BY ACTUAL_DATE,ACTUAL_TIME
```

Output for this query is

[image]

-------------------Records present in the table(Query 2)-----------------------------------------------

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TRAIN_RUNNING_INFO
            WHERE TRAIN_CATG='L'
            AND TRAIN_ID='BGK 140920212028'
```

Output of this query is

[image]

-----------------------------Verification of Division( Query 3)---------------------------------

```
SELECT DISTINCT DIVISION_CODE FROM   TRAIN_RUNNING_INFO
            WHERE TRAIN_CATG='L'
            AND TRAIN_ID='BGK 140920212028' AND TRAIN_START_DATE='14-Sep-2020'
```

Output of this query is

[image]

Comment: This might happen if there are records in TRAIN_RUNNING_INFO having same train_id and train_start_date. Try this query to find records out select count(1), train_id, train_start_date from train_running_info group by train_id, train_start_date having count(1) > 1;

You are filtering table (subquery A) and then join the result with the same again. Are you sure it is necessary?

Comment: Corresponding to one train id & start date there are 8 rows as described in Output 2

Comment: Subquery A was for filtering rows based on rank to get the last record where Actual date & Actual time is highest

Comment: Ok. The division "All" appears because there is a record in TRAIN_RUNNING_INFO  having same TRAIN_ID = 'BGK 140920212028' , TRAIN_START_DATE, and DIVISION_CODE = 'All'. So, you are filtering the trains table in subquery A and then joins it again with the source table. I'm not sure what logic is behind all of these, but I'd recommend you to get rid of joining A and B as it makes all your filtering near to pointless

Comment: If you are able to create a dbfiddle for that case, we can see together where the problem hides

Comment: @radha, I deleted my answer and may be i am wrong and I do believe SQL wont do magic by its own. There is something missing from the data you have shown. e.g. where is `TRAIN_CATG='L'` in Query 2 even though it says `select *` .? As suggested by @ekochergin please create the fiddle. I personally find it hard to imagine rather than having the data with me.

Comment: I got the point , the row corresponding to AII was having some other train_catg so I have to add one condition in join B.TRAIN_CATG='L' & My problem is solved now .Thanks @ekochergin , your one line stucked the logic in my mind

Comment: So sorry I couldn't provide the data , I was about to give after you requested but suddenly logic struck me so why to bother now , Anyways thanks @Sujitmohanty30

Comment: The "why" is because that's how SQL works. Explain exactly what you expect & why you expect it, referencing authoritative documentation, or we don't know what your misconceptions are & you are just asking for yet another presentation & a personalized tutorial Please in code questions give a [mre]. Please use text, not images/links, for what can be expressed in text. Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [help]